# Formatting all labels in R Shiny / CSS tags

Tags: css, r, shiny, shinywidgets

I am trying to reformat all labels in my Shiny app. In doing so, I wanted to fall back on the tags and used the following solution:

```
tags$head(tags$style(
  HTML(
    "label {font-weight: italic; font-family:Times New Roman; margin-bottom:20px;}"
  )
))
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't change anything in my labels from the textInput, input picker, etc.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: The action button does not have a `label` tag. It's `<button id="action" type="button" class="btn btn-default action-button shiny-bound-input">Action</button>`. Inspect the HTML for your the tags.

Comment: Sorry @rbasa, don’t meant the Actiom Button. Just the normal label at input pickers or textinput

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
HTML(
  "label.control-label {
    font-style: italic; 
    font-family: 'Times New Roman'; 
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }"
)
```

or

```
HTML(
  "label {
    font-style: italic !important; 
    font-family: 'Times New Roman' !important; 
    margin-bottom: 20px !important;
  }"
)
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer and sorry for the late reply. Unfortunately it does not work. I use `theme = shinytheme("cosmo")` at the same time and the changes in the tag are not applied :(